# Google Sheets Get Count and Sum for a specific range of cells as per condition

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, sumifs

I have a set of data in Google Sheet as shown below:

| Row No. | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | **Count** | **Person Name** | **Date** | **Status** |
| 1 | 163 | ABC | 03-07-2021 | 1. Done |
| 2 | 26 | ABC | 03-07-2021 | 2. In Progress |
| 3 | 35 | ABC | 03-07-2021 | 2. In Progress |
| 4 | 21 | XYZ | 03-07-2021 | 1. Done |
| 5 | 0 | XYZ | 03-07-2021 | 1. Done |
| 6 | 17 | ABC | 04-07-2021 | 1. Done |
| 7 | 0 | ABC | 04-07-2021 | 1. Done |
| 8 | 267 | ABC | 04-07-2021 | 1. Done |
| 9 | 29 | XYZ | 04-07-2021 | 2. In Progress |
| 10 | 42 | XYZ | 04-07-2021 | 1. Done |

And for these data, I want a tracker which shows all the people in Columns with all dates in Rows (because dates we have to add each day) alongwith the sum of the Count column for each date from the above data and only for ones which are marked "1. Done". So I prepared this tracker and following is the result which is needed as per the data above:

| Row No. | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Date** | **ABC** | **XYZ** |
| 03-07-2021 | 163 | 21 |
| 04-07-2021 | 284 | 42 |

I am just aware that both COUNTIF and SUMIF need to be used to achieve this however not sure how to combine both. Need help to formulate it.

Thanks in advance!

(Sorry, Edited to show Row and Column references )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:D, "select C,sum(A) where D starts with '1' group by C pivot B", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot as the original data was huge.

Comment: Is a weekly count possible after querying out of this data with the counts after each 5 business days? Or any other workaround maybe a formula instead of the query for the initially needed tracker and then a weekly count of it.

Comment: @Irvin you could edit dates as you need and then use for examplle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNEdC.png